# Is that possible to select another radio button, when the other one is already selected and setted in disabled mode?

Tags: java, gwt

In the below code, depending upon the selection(single/multiple selection), iam using the resources images to display accordingly. I have selected the radio button and made it as readonly. Now if i select any other radio button, is that possible to disable the previous selection without removing its readonly mode? only the first radio button field is in readonly mode. all the other fields are editable.

```
case READ_ONLY:
             selectionModel.setSelected(widget, !selectionModel.isSelected(widget));
             if (isSingleSelection) {                        
                   $(checkboxCell).toggleClass(resources.styles().unselected(),
                                        resources.styles().readOnlySelected());
               } else {      
                   $(checkboxCell).toggleClass(resources.styles().unChecked(),
                                        resources.styles().readOnlyChecked());
               }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. It may be easier to explain using an example. Also, this sounds like a confusing way to use radio buttons.

Comment: Java is not Javascript. They are two different languages running in two different environments.

Comment: I have three radio button fields. First field i have selected and made it as non editable. If i select the next radio button field, i should be able to select the second one without any block as well as first radio button should turned to unselected mode. is that is possible?

Comment: You could put the read only radio in a different group than the rest of radios. Though this design does not look ok